# How to merge overlap polygon respectively in one shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, dissolve

I want to merge the polygons of one shapefile if they overlap， but I don't know what to do.
[image]

I try'dissolve' but get only one final polygon. This is not what I need. I want to merge them respectively.

[image]

Comment: After "dissolve" use "multipart to singlepart" .

Comment: the dissolved tool results in a polygon and arbitrarily chooses the attribute of a polygon. When you use the single piece multiple piece tool, you will have more polygons but they will all have the same attributes (the result of the "dissolve" tool)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Two overlapping polygons have different attributes. If you merge these two polygons, the result will be a single polygon but you keep the attributes of which polygon: the first or the second?

If the overlapping polygons have the same attributes you can use the group tool by specifying a grouping field.

Answer (score 0):

If you conduct a union of the layer to itself and then dissolve the contiguous areas of the union layer, you should get what you want. You may need to make a copy of the layer to execute the union.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want as your output.

If you want to keep the original polygons as separate, but remove the overlapping bits (giving them to one or the other polygon), then do what Kingfisher says. I also have a short tutorial on how to deal with those overlapping polygons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKTMhgBTlus

If you wish to selectively merge the polygons together, you can use the select tool to choose the polygons you wish to merge, and then go to Edit>Merge Selected Attributes to merge them into one polygon. You can choose which polygon's attributes are kept in the merged polygon.